# rails form f.select error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to use `meta_search` gem. I have this in my view:

```
<%= f.select :project_type_id_in, 
   raw("<option value=''>-- Proje Types --</option>" + 
   options_from_collection_for_select(ProjectType.all, :id, :name, 
   params[:search][:project_type_id_in].to_i )) %>
```

But when i call the controller I got this error :

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params[:search]` appears to be `nil`, likely because no search option was yet specified.  You can make sure it's initialized before the page loads to avoid this.  Or you can fix it like this:

```
<%= f.select :project_type_id_in, 
      raw("<option value=''>-- Proje Types --</option>" + 
      options_from_collection_for_select(ProjectType.all, :id, :name, 
      params[:search].present? ? params[:search][:project_type_id_in].to_i : nil)) %>
```

Or you can use the `andand` gem to do the same thing a bit cleaner:

```
<%= f.select :project_type_id_in, 
      raw("<option value=''>-- Proje Types --</option>" + 
      options_from_collection_for_select(ProjectType.all, :id, :name, 
      params[:search]&&.[:project_type_id_in].to_i)) %>
```